# identify uniq value with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have this txt file:

```
237708978 5555120825555282
237708978 5555120825555282
237708978 5555120825555281
237708978 5555120825555281
237708978 5555120825555283
239480114 55551208255552814
239480114 55551208255552812
239480114 55551208255552812
239480114 55551208255552814
239480114 55551208255552813
239393704 55551208255552813
239393704 555512082555528133
239393704 555512082555528133
239393704 555512082555528132
239393704 555512082555528132
239393704 555512082555528132
239393704 555512082555528132
239393704 555512082555528131
239393704 555512082555528131
239393704 555512082555528133
239393704 5555120825528132
239393704 5555120825528132
239393704 5555120825528133
239393704 5555120825528132
239393704 5555120825528131
239393704 5555120825528131
239393704 5555120825528133
```

I would like to add column with an unique number every time that column 2 change.
I'm running this awk script (formatted on a single line in my code):

```
 awk  '{ if (NR == 1) { old = $2 ; nr=1 ; print $1, nr, old }
         else
         {{ if($2 == old){ print $1, nr, $2 , old   }
            else { if (old != $2) { nr=nr+1; old=$2; print $1, nr, $2,  old;
       }}}}}' test1.txt
```

and I got

```
237708978 1 5555120825555282 
237708978 1 5555120825555282 5555120825555282
237708978 2 5555120825555281 5555120825555281
237708978 2 5555120825555281 5555120825555281
237708978 3 5555120825555283 5555120825555283
239480114 4 55551208255552814 55551208255552814
239480114 4 55551208255552812 55551208255552814
239480114 4 55551208255552812 55551208255552814
239480114 4 55551208255552814 55551208255552814
239480114 4 55551208255552813 55551208255552814
239393704 4 55551208255552813 55551208255552814
239393704 5 555512082555528133 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528133 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528132 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528132 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528132 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528132 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528131 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528131 555512082555528133
239393704 5 555512082555528133 555512082555528133
239393704 6 5555120825528132 5555120825528132
239393704 6 5555120825528132 5555120825528132
239393704 7 5555120825528133 5555120825528133
239393704 8 5555120825528132 5555120825528132
239393704 9 5555120825528131 5555120825528131
239393704 9 5555120825528131 5555120825528131
239393704 10 5555120825528133 5555120825528133
```

The results seems ok until row 6. When the old variable become too long is not able anymore to compare with the $2. At the end of the file with a shorter value in column 2 the results are again correct.

Any one have an idea?
I can not use associative array because the file is too big, so I can only use if-else condition.

Comment: to be honest, I don't understand your requirement... can you give an expected output based on your input? also check @fedorqui's answer if it solved your problem

Comment: There are many unnecessary braces in your script — three levels of unnecessary braces.  I split your script across multiple lines because the single line of code (a) does not display well and (b) is inscrutable.  Making code readable so it is comprehensible is an important skill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Force the "previous" value to be a string instead of a number:

```
awk '"x" $2 != prev { count++; prev = "x" $2 } {print $1, count, $2}'
```

```
237708978 1 5555120825555282
237708978 1 5555120825555282
237708978 2 5555120825555281
237708978 2 5555120825555281
237708978 3 5555120825555283
239480114 4 55551208255552814
239480114 5 55551208255552812
239480114 5 55551208255552812
239480114 6 55551208255552814
239480114 7 55551208255552813
239393704 7 55551208255552813
239393704 8 555512082555528133
239393704 8 555512082555528133
239393704 9 555512082555528132
239393704 9 555512082555528132
239393704 9 555512082555528132
239393704 9 555512082555528132
239393704 10 555512082555528131
239393704 10 555512082555528131
239393704 11 555512082555528133
239393704 12 5555120825528132
239393704 12 5555120825528132
239393704 13 5555120825528133
239393704 14 5555120825528132
239393704 15 5555120825528131
239393704 15 5555120825528131
239393704 16 5555120825528133
```

Comment: Nice! So apparently the comparison with integers does not suffice and you have to use string. Good investigation and answer.

Comment: +1, though `x` isn't really needed. Concatenating an empty string is sufficient to coerce from a number to a string.

Comment: Thanks!! Nice suggestion! I tough the solution was to use a string variable but i did not now how.